# How to implement angularJS Pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, pagination, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am facing issue with pagination. I have tried several answers including custom filters and every time the data is not displayed. I know the data is been fetched and its present in DOM but I can't seem to figure out why its not displaying the data.

Pagination Controls:

```
// pagination controls
    $scope.currentPage = 1;
    $scope.totalItems = $scope.searchDataValues.length;
    $scope.entryLimit = 8; // items per page
    $scope.noOfPages = Math.ceil($scope.totalItems / $scope.entryLimit);
    $scope.pageChanged    = pageChanged;
    $scope.paginatedList = $scope.searchDataValues.slice(0, $scope.entryLimit);

    function pageChanged(){

        var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.entryLimit),
            end   = begin + $scope.entryLimit;

        $scope.paginatedList = $scope.searchDataValues.slice(begin, end);

    }
```

HTML Side code:

```
<pagination
           ng-change="pageChanged()"
           total-items="totalItems"
           items-per-page="entryLimit"
           ng-model="currentPage"
           max-size="noOfPages"
           class="pagination-sm"
           boundary-links="true">
</pagination>
```

Ng-repeat filter:

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in searchDataValues | orderBy:sortKey:reverse | startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit | limitTo:entryLimit ">
```

Start From filter:

```
app.filter('startFrom', function () {
return function (input, start) {
    if (input === undefined || input === null || input.length === 0) return [];
    start = +start; //parse to int
    console.log(input.slice(start))
    return input.slice(start);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who comes here and reads the post.

I ended up using the code present here: http://embed.plnkr.co/eheFSh/

I did worked, but it broke my sort function. I will try to get both of them to work together.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ui bootstrap pagination directive.
I am using the old version so that syntax may be a little different.
This is an [example](https://jsbin.com/kodoseseta/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: your pageChanged function changes $scope.paginatedList, but your ng-repeat is bound to searchDataValues not to paginatedList.

This could be the source of your trouble, but it's just a guess because you didn't provide all of your code.

Comment: Thanks foir the suggestion, I ended up using: http://embed.plnkr.co/eheFSh/ . But it screwed my sort function. Now I have to figure out how to make both of them play nice with each other.